# Encoding of folders name on windows server and html

Tags: c#, encoding, windows-server-2008

I opened a new account on an American Web-host and I didn't take into account that his server will not support Hebrew chars(on his file system):

[image]

Any way, after coping the gibberish path :

```
<pic src="..\_images\gallery\smallPictures\2010-08-02 âìøéä àåâåñè 2010\" width="150" height="120"></pic>
```

to my XML file and saving it with UTF-8 encoding it worked.

1. is there a way to generate this Gibberish in c#?
2. Is there a way to fix the encoding of the folders (to be in a certain encoding)?